# ERROR in node_modules/@types/lodash/ts4.1/common/lang.d.ts(578,74): error TS2677: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type

Tags: angular, lodash

**This error is related to the lodash.I have added the _.intersection function here,but have no idea what is causing the error.Any help would be appreciated.**

```
import { Directive, OnDestroy, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef,Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./model/user";
import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";
import * as _ from "lodash";


@Directive({
    selector:'[AllowRbac]'
})
export class rbacDirective implements OnDestroy{
    userInfo:User;
    roles:string[];
    sub:Subscription
constructor(private tempRef:TemplateRef<any>,private ViewContainer:ViewContainerRef,
private authService:AuthService){
 this.sub=this.authService.user$.subscribe(res=>{
        this.userInfo=res
    })
}
//to fetch
@Input()set AllowRbac(roles:string[]){
   this.roles=roles;
   this.showAdminUI()

}
 showAdminUI(){
if(!this.roles ||this.roles.length===0|| !this.userInfo){
this.ViewContainer.clear();
return
}
const roles=_.intersection(this.roles,this.userInfo.roles).length > 0
if(roles){
    this.ViewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.tempRef)
}
else{
    this.ViewContainer.clear()
}
 }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

This is a directive to activate role based Authentication for particular users.To hide UI material depending upon the user logged in example admin or normal user

Comment: which version of lodash you are using?

Comment: 4.14.188 ,this version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution as below:
It's work!

```
"@types/lodash": "4.14.149",
```

Thanks ABaranchugov Replay :[reference](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/61772)

Comment: Yes,Typescript version also need to be updated